# Query multiple records from table using derived field

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a legacy database system which deals with property reports and I am attempting to update a query which shows multiple reports within a time period for the same address. I am using MySQL Workbench to run this query.

The table has a UPRN field for unique addresses, which is fine, however addresses can be manually added without a UPRN. The table also has address1, address2, address3, town, postcode fields. There is NO field which contains the whole address as one line.

We already have a query which uses the UPRN field to generate a list of multiple records within a timescale; however, this will obviously exclude multiple reports without a UPRN.

```
 SELECT * FROM
       `rep_base_report` `rep`
        
    WHERE
        `rep`.`UPRN` IN (SELECT 
                `rep2`.`UPRN` AS `UPRN`
            FROM
                `rep_base_report` `rep2`
            WHERE
                `rep2`.`STATUS` = 'LODGED'
                    AND `rep2`.`GENERATED_DATE` > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
            GROUP BY `rep2`.`UPRN`
            HAVING (COUNT(0) > 1)
            ORDER BY `rep2`.`GENERATED_DATE` DESC)
    GROUP BY `rep`.`RepReference`
    ORDER BY `rep`.`UPRN`
```

In my head, if I could CONCAT address1, address2 and postcode and use this as the basis for the check, it would give the appropriate output, but I've no idea how to accomplish this.

I've attempted the following but it's giving fewer values that I was expect (I've manually checked some sample data in Excel to see what I should be expecting).

```
SELECT * 
FROM `rep_base_report` `rep`
WHERE
    @property :=CONCAT(`rep`.`ADDRESS1`, ' ' ,`rep`.`ADDRESS2`, ' ' ,`rep`.`POSTCODE`) IN (
                SELECT @property2 :=CONCAT(`rep2`.`ADDRESS1`, ' ' ,`rep2`.`ADDRESS2`, ' ' ,`rep2`.`POSTCODE`) AS `PROPERTY`
                FROM `rep_base_report` `rep2`
                WHERE `rep2`.`STATUS` = 'LODGED'
                AND `rep2`.`GENERATED_DATE` > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
                GROUP BY @property2
                HAVING COUNT(0) > 1
                ORDER BY `rep2`.`GENERATED_DATE` DESC
            )
GROUP BY `rep`.`RepReference`
ORDER BY `rep`.`UPRN`
```

Comment: Whats with all these unnecessary `( )` sets, it is making the code almost unreadable

Comment: Can you update your post with sample input tables, expected output and MySQL legacy version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT * 
FROM `rep_base_report` `rep`
WHERE
    CONCAT(`rep`.`ADDRESS1`, ' ', `rep`.`ADDRESS2`, ' ', `rep`.`POSTCODE`) IN (
                SELECT CONCAT(`rep2`.`ADDRESS1`, ' ', `rep2`.`ADDRESS2`, ' ', `rep2`.`POSTCODE`) AS `PROPERTY`
                FROM `rep_base_report` `rep2`
                WHERE `rep2`.`STATUS` = 'LODGED'
                AND `rep2`.`GENERATED_DATE` > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
                GROUP BY CONCAT(`rep2`.`ADDRESS1`, ' ', `rep2`.`ADDRESS2`, ' ', `rep2`.`POSTCODE`)
                HAVING COUNT(0) > 1
                ORDER BY `rep2`.`GENERATED_DATE` DESC
            )
GROUP BY `rep`.`RepReference`
ORDER BY `rep`.`UPRN`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).